# Stop Docker from creating root dir when external drive is disconnected?

Tags: docker, ubuntu-18.04

Using linux (Ubuntu 18.04) I have an external hard drive I use for my docker root dir.  All my images are pulled and stored on this external drive.  Docker's root dir is set to `/media/<username>/<drive_name>/Docker/Images` inside the docker daemon.json file.

However, if I start my machine without this drive attached, or if I start docker without this drive attached docker creates a directory called  `/media/<username>/<drive_name>/Docker/Images`.

It even appears to install docker dependencies and populates all the usual sub-folders (although my downloaded docker images are not populated; they will be pulled again if I try to run a container).

How is this creating this directory on my machine and is there any way to stop this behavior?

**Update**: making changes to docker was causing issues so I went a bit simpler and use this VERY simple script to start docker:

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ -d /media/<username>/<drive_name>/Docker/Images ]; then
        echo "Starting Docker!"
        systemctl start docker
else
        echo "Docker drive not present!"
        exit 1
fi
```

Comment: If you run "docker info", what value do you get for "Docker Root Dir"?

Comment: @Mihai Docker root dir is always the same directory, the one listed in the post. If the drive is not attached it creates a directory with that name locally.

Comment: This is normal behaviour. What you could do is edit the docker.service definition and test if the docker root already exists and if it doesn't then don't start docker. Is that an acceptable approach?

Comment: @Mihai that would be great. I’ve disabled docker start on boot altogether and now start it manually. But your approach would be better, in case I start docker without the drive plugged in by mistake. Could you provide an answer with example?